# Apache way to automatic login on a folder

Tags: security, apache-2.4, vps, login, ubuntu-18.04

there is a way to configure apache2 to automatic login a user in a password protected folder ?

I know that with apache someone can make a folder where a user and pass is required, so when a user enter a page of that folder is asked for a login info, but, there is a way to automatic login that user depending of for example IP, referrer etc, cookies?

Comment: You should elaborate on the "automatic login" part. There are two phases in httpd, one is authentication and the other authorization. "Automatic login or authentication" does not exist in httpd unless you mean a previously authenticated user accesing to another resource without a password.

Comment: TY, so maybe i must focus on only autorization? can i have a protected fordel that only iis accesed if some conditions are true but never ask for a paswrod...?

Comment: diya in his/her answer gave you a clue, you can set authentication and set authorization for everyone in another directory, depending on the options you set. First be specific about what you need, then set accordingly, try and let us know what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apache httpd allows you apply logic and ordering when combining different authorization/authentication criteria.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#logic

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html#beyond

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html